# contenteditable br / p / div weirdness

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I create `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`

The behaviour I want is:

Enter key press  = `<p></p>` around the text line

Shift-Enter keys press = `<br/>` after the text line

To get the behaviour I want in Firefox, I have tried creating the following "keypress" event:

```
function(ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode == '13') {
    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    document.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn',false,false);
  }
  return false;
}
```

but Firefox (as at 33.1.1) insists on inserting `<br></br>` on first enter (which then gets wrapped in my paragraph). I understand it to a degree when a line is empty however I do not understand why it is not removed as soon as a character is inserted into the new line.

For example, assume I type:

```
hello<enter>goodbye
```

into the editable field, I will end up with the following markup (using the above event handler)

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>goodbye<br></br></p>
```

The `<br></br>` does indeed disappear if I hit enter again but then I am left with the following markup

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>goodbye</p>
<p><br></br></p>
```

There are 2 problems with this:

1. Users will not necessarily hit the second enter, leaving "invisible" `<br></br>` after the goodbye
2. Alternatively users will hit the second enter and end up with an essentially redundant line containing `<p><br></br></p>`.

In fact the only way I can see to get

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>goodbye</p>
```

ie. what I want, is to to use the following sequence `hello<enter>goodbye<enter><backspace>` which seems patently ridiculous.

At this point I should say that I personally love Firefox as a browser and my strong preference is to keep using it, however for our business clean editing markup is critical, and in Chrome, using the above method (excluding insertBrOnReturn) produces the desired markup (the above keypress event function switches Chrome cleanly to use p rather than its standard div)

So I am in a difficult position, and I would welcome any input from other Firefox enthusiasts as to how the above can be achieved elegantly if indeed it is possible (please don't invest time providing complex hacks though as we are unlikely to use them - in my limited experience complexity is diametrically opposed to reliability)

thanks in advance for any help!

(PS - after working with this, I'm really not sure that the Chrome div implementation is any better - see comments below)

Comment: Just to qualify - when I say "Chrome produces the desired markup", this appears to be with one very notable exception, which is that it appears to use <br> instead of <br/>  ...which is not at all ideal

Comment: Also interestingly both Firefox and Chrome only support 2 lines split by a <shift-enter> br within a single p . If one tries to add a 3rd line via a second <shift-enter> then the the 1st line is "pushed out" upwards into its own p container, leaving only 2 in the current p container

Comment: Sadly there doesn't seem to be any wisdom forthcoming on this and I am now seeing that both FF/Chrome behave VERY wierdly using the "keypress" event function above when the line has a formatting <span>. I am fast coming to the conclusion it is best to pick a browser and go with its native format. Unfortunately for me, although I would vastly prefer <p>, because Chrome offers the <div> wrapper (which is more parse-able than FFs <br/> between lines) I am making the call to go with Chrome. ...but if any FFers come up with a good clean answer going forward, please do let me know here - thanks!!

Comment: Related to my comment 2 above - when using chrome in "native - wrap in DIV" contenteditable mode (ie. without any keypress event), it supports multiple <shift-enter> BRs within an <enter> DIV ie. behaves "correctly"

Comment: contenteditable is like a bad joke. I now discover that - as at Chrome 38 - the Chrome dev team has decreed that the first line should not be wrapped in a div when the enter key is pressed ... but all subsequent lines should be. What on earth!?!

Comment: For completeness: after testing I see that IE 11 IE still inserts P elements sensibly - as did IE 7 - however its developer tools are substandard and its Range support is very poor; thus unfortunately removing the browser as an option.

Comment: My final assessment is this: As at today, in contenteditable browsers appear to care more about what the user sees than about the quality of the underpinning markup created. Also, there is apparently no effort being made to standardise the approach across the browser fraternity. Until this thinking changes, contenteditable will remain second string, and some exciting browser possibilities will remain out of reach.

Comment: Sounds about right. This is why I've always been apprehensive about using contenteditable (and I don't bother with it, at all).